# fixing header to top of screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a header section holding my nav bar and an image. It's a black header on a white background.

```
<header id="header">
  <img id="header-img" src="https://ruwix.com/rubiks-cube-image.php?n=4&fl=xpxyowrrbygywygowbgwyowrrxyorgybrrwyrwybwyowbgwb&bg=AABBBB&m=xy&f=png&size=200&b=40&d=5" height=100 width=100>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#catalogue">Catalogue</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I want to have it fixed to the top of my screen to have it always in view.

So far my CSS is

```
.nav-list-link {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

The rest of the page rises up behind it. When I adjust the width to 100%, it expands to the entire row length but leaves some space on it's left. Also, there is space above it that I can't seem to shrink.

I want to have the header at the top of the page with no extra space at the top or sides.

Comment: Replace `width` with `top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [div after a div which position is fixed in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405528/div-after-a-div-which-position-is-fixed-in-css)

Answer (score 2):

**I solved the problem and improved your code**

```css
body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>

<div class="navbar">
<img id="header-img" src="https://ruwix.com/rubiks-cube-image.php?n=4&fl=xpxyowrrbygywygowbgwyowrrxyorgybrrwyrwybwyowbgwb&bg=AABBBB&m=xy&f=png&size=200&b=40&d=5" height=50 width=50 style="float: left">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</header>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Fixed Top Navbar</h1>
  <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
  <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a class in you css but it isn't in your ul tag where i think it should be. The space that remains on you left could be the padding-left:10px in you css, keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 0):

On your header selector remove the width property and add the following properties:

```
#header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

This will keep it fixed to the top of your browser window

Comment: This does not solve the problem that text from content below gets partially hidden and goes behind the header

Comment: @WandMaker You can apply a container to your content and then margin-top the content to push it down. However, a better solution would be to set it to default position then using some JavaScript trigger an event when the user scrolls which changes the header to position fixed.